# Why is Clang automatically adding attributes to my functions?

Tags: c++, c, assembly, llvm, compiler-optimization

I have a piece of code that I'm trying to turn into LLVM bitcode:

```
int main() {
    volatile double n = 0.45;
    for (int j = 0; j < 32; j++) {
        n *= j;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I run the following command on it:

```
clang -O0 -S -emit-llvm TrainingCode/trainingCode.cpp -o TrainingCode/trainingCode.ll
```

to generate the following LLVM bitcode (take note of the 6th line, the one with "Function Attrs"):

```
; ModuleID = 'TrainingCode/trainingCode.cpp'
source_filename = "TrainingCode/trainingCode.cpp"
target datalayout = "e-m:e-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128"
target triple = "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"

; Function Attrs: noinline norecurse nounwind optnone uwtable
define i32 @main() #0 {
entry:
  %retval = alloca i32, align 4
  %n = alloca double, align 8
  %j = alloca i32, align 4
  store i32 0, i32* %retval, align 4
  store double 4.500000e-01, double* %n, align 8
  store i32 0, i32* %j, align 4
  br label %for.cond

for.cond:                                         ; preds = %for.inc, %entry
  %0 = load i32, i32* %j, align 4
  %cmp = icmp slt i32 %0, 32
  br i1 %cmp, label %for.body, label %for.end

for.body:                                         ; preds = %for.cond
  %1 = load i32, i32* %j, align 4
  %conv = sitofp i32 %1 to double
  %2 = load double, double* %n, align 8
  %mul = fmul double %2, %conv
  store double %mul, double* %n, align 8
  br label %for.inc

for.inc:                                          ; preds = %for.body
  %3 = load i32, i32* %j, align 4
  %inc = add nsw i32 %3, 1
  store i32 %inc, i32* %j, align 4
  br label %for.cond

for.end:                                          ; preds = %for.cond
  ret i32 0
}

attributes #0 = { noinline norecurse nounwind optnone uwtable "correctly-rounded-divide-sqrt-fp-math"="false" "disable-tail-calls"="false" "less-precise-fpmad"="false" "no-frame-pointer-elim"="true" "no-frame-pointer-elim-non-leaf" "no-infs-fp-math"="false" "no-jump-tables"="false" "no-nans-fp-math"="false" "no-signed-zeros-fp-math"="false" "no-trapping-math"="false" "stack-protector-buffer-size"="8" "target-cpu"="x86-64" "target-features"="+fxsr,+mmx,+sse,+sse2,+x87" "unsafe-fp-math"="false" "use-soft-float"="false" }

!llvm.module.flags = !{!0}
!llvm.ident = !{!1}

!0 = !{i32 1, !"wchar_size", i32 4}
!1 = !{!"clang version 5.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_500/final)"}
```

Why is clang adding the `optnone` attribute to `main`? I need LLVM to run various transformation passes on the bitcode and the `optnone` attribute is causing LLVM to skip over main... I need this attribute to not be added.

Compiling with `-O1` seems to fix this, however this is unacceptable because I need Clang to give me unoptimized code. I want LLVM to optimize the unoptimized code given to me by Clang, but the presence of the `optnone` attribute is causing LLVM to not perform any optimizations.

Comment: Try compiling with `-O1` or higher

Comment: @Justin I need Clang to give me unoptimized code though.

Comment: Then why is it a problem that you have `optnone`?

Comment: @Justin Because I want LLVM to optimize the unoptimized code given to me by Clang, but the presence of the the `optnone` attribute is causing LLVM to not perform any optimizations.

Comment: I can't imagine a production scenario where that would be useful.... Why would you want to run LLVM separately? Regardless, what you could do is compile twice, once with optimizations and once without.

Comment: @Justin: presumably he's debugging or working on LLVM.  related: I've read that `rustcc` generates LLVM-IR that needs a lot of optimization work by the back-end.  If you're looking for LLVM-IR input that needs a lot of optimization by the back-end, try that.

Comment: @Justin It's not a production scenario, I'm doing research into compiler optimization techniques using LLVM and need unoptimized bitcode to do this. How would compiling twice solve my problem? I would then have unoptimized code with the attribute and optimized code without it, neither of which is useful to me...

Comment: You're question doesn't make any sense, for the reason Justin gave, but the obvious solution is to just write a program to strip the undesired attribute from the LLVM IR.

Comment: I think the reason for this is so clang can use the correct optimization level for each function when doing LTO.

Comment: I just tried the same segment with LLVM/Clang 3.7.0 and trunk (6.0.0) and the `optnone` attribute appears in the later version. So, I guess somewhere in between there's a patch that adds such behaviour. What if you play around with `removeFnAttr` as documented [here](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Function.html)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are clang options to disable its optimization of the LLVM-IR.  See https://reviews.llvm.org/D28047 for discussion of a patch that would change them, and [@Anton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47504219/why-is-clang-automatically-adding-attributes-to-my-functions/47524527#47524527) to this question for more about using it.  Some or all of these options might be the right thing:

`clang -O1 -mllvm -disable-llvm-optzns -disable-llvm-passes`

(The resolution of that discussion was commit rL290392: `Make '-disable-llvm-optzns' an alias for '-disable-llvm-passes'`, so current clang only needs one.)

---

Or there's the dumb way:  A simple workaround is possible with `sed` (or your favourite text-processing tool).

You're only using this on compiler-generated code, so you don't have to worry about using regexes to parse free-form hand-written code.  Thus you can match fixed formatting that the compiler always uses to make sure you operate only on the correct lines.

```
# tested and works on the .ll in your question
sed -i '/^; Function Attrs:\|^attributes #/ s/optnone //'   *.ll
```

Replaces the first occurence of `optnone` (with a trailing space) with the empty string, on lines that start with `attributes #` (the one that matters) or with `; Function Attrs:` (the comment).

It's an `s///` command controlled by a `/foo\|bar/` address regex to select which lines it operates on.

`sed -i` rewrites the input file(s) in-place.

Answer (score 5):

This is expected. The -O0 output is not intended for further optimizations, some bits of IR are not emitted at all in order to reduce the compilation time.

So, you'd need to use -O1 -mllvm -disable-llvm-optzns if you want to get unoptimized IR that may be optimized later.

Comment: Ah, yes a clang patch review mentions this option and describes it as "what you want to get raw LLVM-IR out of clang".  https://reviews.llvm.org/D28047.  See also discussion on that patch review re the related `-disable-llvm-passes`; you might want both in older clang, and I didn't read carefully to see what they decided to do.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry not a solution, but  maybe a clue.

But be clang version released or environment variables.

Taking your code on OS X with XCODE 9:

```
$ clang -O0 -S -emit-llvm test.cpp  -o test2.ll

$ more test2.ll
; ModuleID = 'test.cpp'
source_filename = "test.cpp"
target datalayout = "e-m:o-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128"
target triple = "x86_64-apple-macosx10.12.0"

; Function Attrs: norecurse nounwind ssp uwtable
define i32 @main() #0 {
  %1 = alloca i32, align 4
  %2 = alloca double, align 8
```

...

```
; <label>:15:                                     ; preds = %4
  ret i32 0
}

attributes #0 = { norecurse nounwind ssp uwtable "correctly-rounded-divide-sqrt-fp-math"="false" "disable-tail-calls"="false" "less-precise-fpmad"="false" "no-frame-pointer-elim"="true" "no-frame-pointer-elim-non-leaf" "no-infs-fp-math"="false" "no-jump-tables"="false" "no-nans-fp-math"="false" "no-signed-zeros-fp-math"="false" "stack-protector-buffer-size"="8" "target-cpu"="penryn" "target-features"="+cx16,+fxsr,+mmx,+sse,+sse2,+sse3,+sse4.1,+ssse3,+x87" "unsafe-fp-math"="false" "use-soft-float"="false" }

!llvm.module.flags = !{!0}
!llvm.ident = !{!1}

!0 = !{i32 1, !"PIC Level", i32 2}
!1 = !{!"Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)"}
```

Comment: So somewhere in Apple's version of clang, there's a patch that makes it leave out the `optnone` attribute?  Maybe worth checking on http://gcc.godbolt.org/ to see if newer or older mainline clang versions are like that.