# Convert LLVM IR to higher optimization level

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

I have compiled the C code to `LLVM` IR code with `-O0` optimization.

How can I convert this `-O0` LLVM IR code to the `-O3` `LLVM` IR code "without the C code"?

I have tried below:

```
clang -O3 -S -emit-llvm O0.ll -o O3.ll
```

and

```
opt -O3 -S O0.ll -o O3.ll
```

but the output is still `-O0` level.

Thank you.

Comment: `opt` should do what you are expecting. Can you post a sample? Are they identical?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Clang automatically adding attributes to my functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47504219/why-is-clang-automatically-adding-attributes-to-my-functions)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure when the change happened (I think it's `LLVM` 3.9.0 and on), but when you compile to bitcode functions get annotated with the `optnone` attribute and further optimizations are not performed.

Have a look for a relevant SO discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47504219/why-is-clang-automatically-adding-attributes-to-my-functions).

What is suggested is to do this:

```
clang -emit-llvm -O1 -mllvm -disable-llvm-optzns -disable-llvm-passes foo.c -o foo.bc
```

For `LLVM` 3.8.0 and earlier (I think) what you have already been doing is enough.

So, once you obtain that bitcode (without the `optnone`) argument, you can use `opt` as you've already been doing.

Comment: Intellectual curiosity now makes me want to write a transformation to remove all the `optnone` attributes, but I don't think it would end pretty.

Comment: haha, yeah, but I'm not sure about those cases that `optnone` is there for a reason.